# I want to do some operation and make new array of object from result i'm getting in another AOB

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

developers I hope you all are doing great and healthy in this time,

1. I want to make some operation like total of `Total_Count` of two or more different object with same `MAC` address
2. Count percentage based on `Status = "Complete"`, so `Total(of where Status = "Complete") / Total (of same MAC address) * 100`

Let me show the result and expecting output,

#### Result I'm getting

```
data = [
  {
    Device_MAC: "45:6F:28:C1:2E:C0",
    Status: "Complete",
    Total: 1,
    Device_Name: "Device 1",
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1",
    Status: "Complete",
    Total: 2,
    Device_Name: "Device 2",
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1",
    Status: "Incomplete",
    Total: 4,
    Device_Name: "Device 2",
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0",
    Status: "Complete",
    Total: 63,
    Device_Name: "Device 3",
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0",
    Status: "Incomplete",
    Total: 34,
    Device_Name: "Device 3",
  },
];
```

Now as you can see there's specific key named `Total` which describe count of some device based on `Status`

And I want result with `Percentage`  key where `(Total Status Complete / Total Complete + Total Incomplete) * 100`

For eg, For `Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1"`, Total Complete = `2` and Total Complete(2) + Incomplete(4) = `6`

So my percentage will be `(2 / 6) * 100`.

#### Output I want based on unique MAC :

1. Total Of Complete + Incomplete
2. Percentage
3. No need of Status Key-value

```
output = [
  {
    Device_MAC: "45:6F:28:C1:2E:C0",
    Total: 1,
    Percentage:100,
    Device_Name: "Device 1",
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1",
    Total: 6,
    Percentage:50,
    Device_Name: "Device 2",
  },
  {
    Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0",
    Total: 97,
    Percentage:64.94,
    Device_Name: "Device 3",
  },
];
```

#### How much I tried :

```
if (data.length) {
  let uniqueMac = [
    ...new Set(
      data.map((obj) => {
        return obj.Device_MAC;
      })
    ),
  ];

  uniqueMac.forEach((mac) => {
   //Don't know how to handle here
  });
}
```

#### THANK YOU FOR YOUR CONTRIBUTION !!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a fairly standard 'groupBy' using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group elements by MAC address and then mapping the results to calculate the percentage.

```js
const
  data = [{ Device_MAC: "45:6F:28:C1:2E:C0", Status: "Complete", Total: 1, Device_Name: "Device 1", }, { Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1", Status: "Complete", Total: 2, Device_Name: "Device 2", }, { Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1", Status: "Incomplete", Total: 4, Device_Name: "Device 2", }, { Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0", Status: "Complete", Total: 63, Device_Name: "Device 3", }, { Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0", Status: "Incomplete", Total: 34, Device_Name: "Device 3", },],

  result = Object
    .values(
      data
        .reduce((a, { Status, Total, ...rest }) => (
          (a[rest.Device_MAC] ??= { ...rest, Complete: 0, Incomplete: 0 })[Status] += Total, a
        ), {})
    )
    .map(({ Complete, Incomplete, ...rest }) => (
      {
        ...rest,
        Total: (Complete + Incomplete),
        Percentage: ((Complete / (Complete + Incomplete)) * 100).toFixed(2) || 0,
      }
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Request you to please look out my answer too, and can you please vote up my question and answer, it'll help me lot.

Comment: I'm not able to use `??=` and `+=` logical signs in my node code, it runs great in local but it gives error when deploying on server, can you please tell me the reason, why this happens ?

Comment: `??=` is the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and isn't fully supported yet. You can use a logical OR short circuit instead `(a[rest.Device_MAC] || (a[rest.Device_MAC] = { ... }))` but I don't see why the addition assignment wouldn't be working as it has been around forever.

Answer (score 0):

#### So I worked on it, solved by self.

Still, I want your review on my answer, it's good or not.
Leave a comment. -:)

```
let data = [{ Device_MAC: "45:6F:28:C1:2E:C0", Status: "Complete", Total: 1, Device_Name: "Device 1", }, { Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1", Status: "Complete", Total: 2, Device_Name: "Device 2", }, { Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C1", Status: "Incomplete", Total: 4, Device_Name: "Device 2", }, { Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0", Status: "Complete", Total: 63, Device_Name: "Device 3", }, { Device_MAC: "44:6F:28:C1:2E:C0", Status: "Incomplete", Total: 34, Device_Name: "Device 3", },],


let finalResult = [];

if (data.length) {
  let uniqueMac = [
    ...new Set(
      data.map((obj) => {
        return obj.Device_MAC;
      })
    ),
  ];

  uniqueMac.forEach((mac) => {
    let Incomplete = data.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.Device_MAC == mac && obj.Status == "Incomplete";
    });
    let Complete = data.filter((obj) => {
      return obj.Device_MAC == mac && obj.Status == "Complete";
    });

    let obj = Incomplete && Incomplete.length ? Incomplete[0] : Complete[0];
    delete obj.Status;

    let Total = null,
      Compliance = null;
    if (Incomplete && Incomplete.length) {
      Incomplete = Incomplete[0];
      Total += Incomplete.Total_Swipe;
    }
    if (Complete && Complete.length) {
      Complete = Complete[0];
      Total += Complete.Total_Swipe;
      obj.Compliance = ((Complete.Total_Swipe / Total) * 100).toFixed(2);
    } else {
      obj.Compliance = ((Incomplete.Total_Swipe / Total) * 100).toFixed(2);
    }
    finalResult.push(obj);
  });
}

console.log(finalResult);
```